# How do slice and select only the first characters- like you would use str() for a character string, but for a numeric feature?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, feature-engineering

I am trying to slice first 3 digits of the feature Zip Code and create a new variable off of that.

Comment: Convert it to a string and then slice it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Zip = 300123
newZip = Zip//1000
print(newZip)
```

Comment: it's just an example bro, :D the solution is the same for 5, 6, 10, 1000 digits :D
and how did say that he wants exactly the US Zip?

Comment: The first 3 digits tell us about sectional center facilities- or zones rather. This actually solved my problem. The real format is df['zipslice'] = df['zip']//100.

Answer (score -1):

```py
zipcode = 75012
sliced_zipcode = str(zipcode)[:3]

# If you want the result in integer
three_digits_zipcode = int(str(zipcode)[:3])

# If you want to apply this in a dataframe
import pandas as pd

df['three_digits_zip'] = df['zipcode'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[:3]))
```

Comment: This code was not able to work for me because it says it only works on strings. I also tried to transform the entire feature using pd.Categorical but it still says that the feature is an integer when I check the dtypes().

Comment: can you show your code please. Cause the `str()` part is actually to turn it into string

Comment: can I know why this was voted down ? sorry for helping then